# showing dependency error using firebase

Tags: android

i am trying to use firebase for realtime database.project ran successfully some times ago but now showing this error...

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not resolve com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+.
  >    Required by:
  >        project:app:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+.
  >   Failed to list versions for com.firebase:firebase-client-android.
  >   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/maven-metadata.xml.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/maven-metadata.xml'.
  >   jcenter.bintray.com
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashik.project"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.dakatso:livebutton:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation provided for the Firebase at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

The developers have mentioned of the same issue that you are facing.

"compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

// Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
// the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager"

So try updating your SDK tools and this should be resolved.

Comment: Try updating once your SDK and let me know